# PHP - Losing $_SESSION variable index

Tags: php, session

I want to pass an array to another page, then use elements in that array to make JSON, and then echo it out for the first page to access it.

Right now I can send the array to the other page, I then format it how I want, I echo it out for the first page to get, but then when I try to echo fetch_get_contents of the url I'm echoing the info on, it all of a sudden breaks the $_SESSION variable.

This is in my first file

```
$_SESSION['map'] = $rowContentArray;
$url2 = "http:....php";
```

in my second file I can get the array fine and I do everything I want with it
I echo out the info I want from my other page, then when i try to access the info on the first page again, it breaks

just by adding this last line

```
$_SESSION['map'] = $rowContentArray;
$url2 = "http:.....php";
echo file_get_contents($url2, true);
```

I get the error that the index i'm using to access the array in the $_SESSION variable is undefined in my second file

```
$map = $_SESSION['map'];
```

error:

Notice: Undefined index: map

On the first file, I can echo out any random string after the session stuff and everything still works..but when i try to echo the url contents it breaks.

I am very confused as to what could be causing the session variable to be lost.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Add `session_start()` at the top of each file

Comment: Are you calling [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php) in all pages?

Comment: yes i do have session_start() in both pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mate, there is no any errors in your scripts! Actually this is exactly the expected behavior.

When you access the page from your browser a specific `COOKIE` is set and the `$_SESSION` array is bind to this cookie.

When you access the page with `file_get_contents($url2, true);` The server is assigning another `COOKIE`with brand new `$_SESSION` array bind to it.

Obviously the second `$_SESSION` array do not have `map` key set, so as expected you are getting
`Notice: Undefined index: map`

Keep in mind that the variable `$_SESSION` is session specific, so if you have say 1000 simultaneously opened sessions to the server you have 1000 different versions of `$_SESSION` variable.

Check this article to get the things clearly: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie

If you can define what is your specific use case we will be able to help you more.

The usual approach is to use `GET` or `POST` variables when you need to transfer data between different sessions. For example in your case you can try:
`file_get_contents($url2 . '?map=' . json_encode($rowContentArray));`

Then instead in the `$_SESSION['map']` you will get your array in `$_GET['map']`

If the array `$rowContentArray` is big enough not to fit as a `GET` parameter, then you will have to use `POST` method.

Comment: ahh that makes sense. I was trying to use get and pass it through the url before, and was having trouble, so i switched to try and use session.. and still had trouble haha

Comment: so i switched back to trying to use get, and now it says 'map' is an undefined index from the $_GET['map'];

Comment: i added this line after the $url2

Comment: file_get_contents($url2 . '?map=' . json_encode($rowContentArray)); and then said $map = $_GET['map']; and it says undefined index map

Comment: using the url fetch and the session in the same script caused problems, like you notified me. does doing the url fetch with passing different variables to different scripts cause problems as well for the same reason of different sessions?

Comment: Can you post the result of `print_r($_GET);` together with the full URL, so we know what is there and what is missing?